# Windows XPe: How to clear entire screen

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp-embedded

We have an ermbedded system running windows XPe. After startup we do a self test of some of the hardware. If the hardware is defective we want to change the entire screen to a single colour hiding everything that might otherwise be visible: taskbar, any open windows etc. And ideally we want to do this from a batch file, without installing any extra software. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the embedded version of windows, but I believe what you can do is just call CreateWindow that covers the entire screen with the z-order at the top.  No clue how you do this from a batch file without some custom code for it to launch.

Comment: @selbie: CreateWindow with topmost flags etc will do it, until another window is opened that does the same thing. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: This is not really how XPe works.  You use the builder to create a custom version of XP that matches the specific embedded hardware.  Different hardware begets different XPe images.  So if the actual hardware doesn't support video then you just select the headless option in the builder.